# Execute oracle function which returns a varchar2 and a refcursor (oracle client .net)

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g, oracleclient

How to write a function (.net oracle client) which execute an oracle function and returns a varchar2 and aref cursor.
My oracle function is like

```
  Function function_name(arg1 in number, arg2 in varchar2, out_cursor out cursorType) 
  return varchar2
```

Comment: What did you try and how does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return one value as a function return value and another value as an out parameter with  `Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output`